# How can I hide an specific div element without id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I'm wondering how I can hide and element DIV without ID in Javascript.

This is the code:

```
<div onclick='hideElement(this);'><b>Element 1</b>
Text 1
</div>
<div onclick='hideElement(this);'><b>Element 2</b>
Text 2
</div>
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hide the div's when I click them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hideElement(element){
    element.style.display = "none";
}
```

since you pass `this` as argument you do not need to 'catch' the element from it's ID